# log4j file appender not working

Tags: java, log4j

am using log4j-1.2.15.jar for enable logging .and its writing all logs to a file.
this is what in my log4j.properties.

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, fileout
log4j.appender.fileout = log.NewLogForEachRunFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileout.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileout.File = D:/log/logs.log
```

It was working fine when am trying to run this from my local server configured in eclipse.
But the same is not working when i had deployed that into the production development enviornment.This is what am getting in the console.

```
no output stream or file set for the appender named [fileout]
```

Can anyone give a solution.?

Comment: Where do you put log4j.properties on production env?

Comment: in the same location ../WEB-INF/classes/

Answer (score 4):

Your configuration looks ok. I assume the `D:/log/logs.log` is available in production environment.

You might want to try log4j configuration debugging by setting `-Dlog4j.debug` on the command line. It often points out useful configuration errors.

Comment: it gets solved..the issue is not in log4j.properties file..am creating the log files using NewLogForEachRunFileAppender class ..where the log files to be written depends on one properties file loaded inside this class..and this file is not getting loaded properly because of some path issue...thanx for your response.

Comment: print the properties file path in console and start the server in console mode..in path some spaces are automatically get replaced with %20.and that was the issue..